# Repeating page numbers (in Kaobook + Vertical Line Title Page)

Tags: titles, page-numbering, front-matter, kaobook

I'm making a document using two templates: Kaobook (for the main style of the book) and Vertical Line Title Page (for the title page).

The title page section (which includes the actual title page, the copyright page, the dedication and the TOC) has a roman numbering and the rest has arabic numbers.

The problem is that the first two pages are "i" and "ii" and then it starts again in "i". The main body (the part with the arabic numbers is OK).

I tried moving around the place of the `maketitle`, deleting the `\begin{titlepage}`, and deleting the `\frontmatter`.

Any ideas of what could be the conflict?

[Edit]

I solved it. While trying to make the MWE that @modnar suggested, I realised that the problem did not happen if I removed the `maketitle`. The `maketitle` was adding two empty pages (since I did not have any data for it in the preamble, I guess) at the beginning.

The `\begin{titlepage}` and the `\end{titlepage}` where enough.

Comment: A MWE would be nice.

Comment: @modnar thanks for the advice. I'm on it.